# Can't figure out this error (passing an array of structs to function): Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

Tags: c++

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;



struct employeeInfo{
    int id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double salary;
};

void loadArray(employeeInfo infoArray[]);
//void sortArrayName(employeeInfo, employeeInfo);

int main(){
      employeeInfo infoArray[6];
  //  employeeInfo infoArrayLast[100]; // sorted by last name
    //employeeInfo infoArraySalary[100]; // sorted by salary


    loadArray(&infoArray[6]);
    //  sortArrayName(infoArray[100], infoArrayLast[100]);

}

void loadArray(employeeInfo infoArray[]){
    ifstream fileData;
    int count;
    int arraySize;
//    employeeInfo infoArray[100];
    fileData.open("employees.txt");

    while(!fileData.eof()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            fileData >> infoArray[i].id >> infoArray[i].firstName >> infoArray[i].lastName >> infoArray[i].salary;
            count++;
        }
    }
    arraySize = count;

    for(int i = 0; i< arraySize; i++){

        cout << infoArray[i].id << infoArray[i].firstName << infoArray[i].lastName << infoArray[i].salary << endl;

    }
}
```

When i use `fileData >>` in the last function is when the error appears:

```
{__c1 = __c2;}
```

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)"

employees.txt is opening correctly and this is its contents:

```
1000 George Washington 10000
2000 John Adams 15000
1212 Thomas Jefferson 34000
1313 Abraham Lincoln 45000
1515 Jimmy Carter 78000
1717 George Bush 80000
```

I think my problem is somewhere in the function definition, call, or declaration, but I've tried many many different combinations and i still can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: This is why they have debuggers. What did yours say?

Comment: I've been programming for a lot of years, and I've never seen address 0x1 as a valid address...

Comment: @tadman this is just an intro to computer science course so we haven't really learned to use them yet. I'm using breakpoints in xCode and everything goes fine until the fileData >> line, which redirects me to that error

Comment: @John3136 What would this imply? Do my function declaration/call/definitions all match up?

Comment: When you have a hard crash like this, here's your first lesson: Step one is to open it with your debugger and find out why it halts. With any luck it will still crash. The worst thing is when it refuses to crash when run in a debugger, but always crashes when you don't. When writing compiled code don't be afraid to try the debugger. It's often very educational, especially when you step through your code to see how it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function call `loadArray(&infoArray[6]);` will pass the address of the 7th element to your function.  Your array only has 6 elements so this will result in an out of bounds access.

I believe you want to pass the array itself, `loadArray(infoArray);

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off of Huynh. When you add to count you start at one. IE Count = count +1. This can be fixed by adding -1 to arraySize = count

```
  while(!fileData.eof()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            fileData >> infoArray[i].id >> infoArray[i].firstName >> infoArray[i].lastName >> infoArray[i].salary;
            count++;
        }
    }
    arraySize = count -1;

    for(int i = 0; i< arraySize; i++){

        cout << infoArray[i].id << infoArray[i].firstName << infoArray[i].lastName << infoArray[i].salary << endl;

    }
}
```

Also lastly you could check the size of the array for your for loop insted using count by doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(infoArray)/sizeof(*infoArray) ; i++)
```

Comment: Both of those are great to know. The whole array size (i.e. index starts at 0 instead of 1) idea and basic counting like that are incredibly easy, but I find myself often making minor mistakes like adding 1 too much or 1 too little. I had no idea 'sizeof' was even a function for arrays, my professor probably intentionally didn't tell us so we could learn to count with loops, but this is very useful to know. Thanks a lot!